# Alternative to Naphthalene Sublimation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, chemical-compounds

I work in a wind tunnel that uses [Naphthalene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naphthalene) for flow visualization. Specifically we use it to see the location of transition from laminar to turbulent flow. We mix it with acetone and spray it on with an automotive paint gun. This leaves a thin white powder on the surface of a model that we are testing.

Naphthalene sublimates at room temperature and the rate of sublimation is proportional to the skin friction. Turbulent flow has higher skin friction so it is easy to see the boundary between laminar and turbulent regions.

The problem is that naphthalene is the main ingredient in mothballs and *smells quite horrible*. The smell lingers for weeks and soaks into my clothes.

**Question:**
**What are some potential alternatives that we could use? Are there any other non-toxic* chemicals that sublimate at room temperature?**

*We make sure and limit the amount of naphthalene we use to stay within the permissible exposure limit.

Comment: You could probably make the "economics argument" that there isn't an inexpensive, safe alternative, i.e., wind tunnels are fairly common so if there was one they'd probably be using it. But you should also ask at the chemistry .SE also.

Comment: In regards to above comment: Cross-posting to other SE sites is generally frowned up when done in short time spans (less than a day or two). If little/no success here after a few days, you can always flag for migration (or delete & ask elsewhere).

Comment: Could one use thermal imaging? If the model surface is heated with e.g. an electrical heating foil or using radiation (paint it dark in the IR and use an IR emitter  to heat it evenly), would the difference in cooling by the flow be visible with a thermal camera?

Comment: @CuriousOne That is a good idea! We do use IR thermography for this purpose as well and when possible prefer this method. Some models are from long ago and electrical heating would be difficult to add. We have tried using heat lamps but had lots of problems with reflections. And a thick coat of insulative paint is necessary to hold a thermal gradient on aluminum models.

Comment: Oh, cool! I honestly didn't know this, I was just guessing that it may work. After I wrote this I kind of began going trough the motions of what the problems might be with the IR method may be and the reflection problem obviously popped up, too, for models that have strong changes in their angles, like at the transition from wings to cabin body... that's when I began appreciating the naphthalene method, even with its obvious downside. Sorry that I couldn't do more than to reinvent the wheel for you... :-(